Capture first observation every 30 days, drop those that are within the 30 day window
I am having unfortunate luck working on code to capture the first observation every 30 days from a previous observation. So, the 30-day window would reset upon a new 30+day observation from the last. This would be by a grouping ID. I can see that being difficult to understand so I wrote out an example dataset and a variable identifying what I would want to keep and delete. In addition, the code I am currently experimenting with.
df <- data.frame(id = c("a","a","a","a","a",'a',"b","b","b","b","b","b"),
                date = c('12/01/22','12/15/22','01/02/22','02/03/22','02/17/22','04/15/22',
                         '12/01/22','02/02/22','03/15/22','03/31/22','04/15/22','05/31/22'),
                keep = c('keep','delete','keep','keep','delete','keep',
                         'keep','keep','keep','delete','keep','keep'))
cutoff <- 30

df.t <- df %>% 
  # if date is < cutoff days of first date, maintain the same group
  # else create a new group
  group_by(g= accumulate(date, ~ if (.y - .x < cutoff) .x else .y)) %>%  
  # for each group select the first row
  slice_head(n = 1) %>% 
  # ungroup and remove grouping variable
  ungroup()                 

Updated with more relevant data for further assistance! Thank you!
structure(list(id_code = c("CH02-1", "CH02-10", "CH02-10", "CH02-10", 
"CH02-100", "CH02-100", "CH02-1000", "CH02-1001", "CH02-1002", 
"CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", 
"CH02-1003", "CH02-1004", "CH02-1004", "CH02-1005", "CH02-1006", 
"CH02-1007", "CH02-1007", "CH02-1007", "CH02-1008", "CH02-1009", 
"CH02-101", "CH02-101", "CH02-101", "CH02-101", "CH02-1010", 
"CH02-1010", "CH02-1011", "CH02-1011", "CH02-1012", "CH02-1012", 
"CH02-1013", "CH02-1014", "CH02-1015", "CH02-1016", "CH02-1017", 
"CH02-1017", "CH02-1018", "CH02-1019", "CH02-1019", "CH02-1019", 
"CH02-102", "CH02-102", "CH02-1020", "CH02-1021", "CH02-1022", 
"CH02-1022"), date = structure(c(18789, 19014, 19041, 19048, 
18950, 18961, 18786, 18767, 18950, 18951, 18952, 18970, 18995, 
18996, 18860, 19043, 19045, 18702, 18709, 18814, 18818, 18846, 
18795, 18926, 18789, 18793, 18810, 18820, 18697, 18702, 18748, 
18765, 18783, 18785, 18796, 18901, 18690, 18966, 18817, 18825, 
18950, 18695, 18701, 18708, 18987, 19017, 18782, 18992, 18724, 
18739), class = "Date"), row = 1:50), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


If you want to work on "days" in a date column, you need a Date class, see [?as.Date])(https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) for how to fix your data. ("Math"-like operations on strings will not work.)

@r2evans - I made this as example from my original dataset. I know well of the date format. Please forgive that I did not include that one line of code in my example I prepared for you all. Even if you change it to date, format, it still does not work out. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.

(We can only understand your problem based on what's in the question. I'd encourage you to edit it to reflect your issue as specifically as possible. If you've already converted to date, please reflect that so our suggestions can be as relevant as possible.)

Please no animosity or snark. If you know well the date format, many others do not, and they think they can do '12/01/22' - '11/15/22' to get the number of days. It can be onerous to infer what problems in the data are "known" (i.e., just typos or shortcuts or whatever) to the OP and what are real. In this case, it is all-too-common for people to try to do running periods or similar on strings instead of dates and not know the difference. It's easy enough to add a simple mutate(..) to your data.frame(...) here so that somebody else doesn't wonder the same thing about your data.

I have noted this, thank you.

Perhaps others will, but I can't see a way around a loop.  Essentially, the function my_f() loops through the dates and then finds ones that are within 30 days (ahead) and removes them.  I used split() to make a list of data frames by id and then apply the function to each one separately.  This would allow you to take advantage of multiple cores with parallel::mclapply() if you wanted to.
library(dplyr)  
df <- structure(list(id_code = c("CH02-1", "CH02-10", "CH02-10", "CH02-10", 
"CH02-100", "CH02-100", "CH02-1000", "CH02-1001", "CH02-1002", 
"CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", "CH02-1002", 
"CH02-1003", "CH02-1004", "CH02-1004", "CH02-1005", "CH02-1006", 
"CH02-1007", "CH02-1007", "CH02-1007", "CH02-1008", "CH02-1009", 
"CH02-101", "CH02-101", "CH02-101", "CH02-101", "CH02-1010", 
"CH02-1010", "CH02-1011", "CH02-1011", "CH02-1012", "CH02-1012", 
"CH02-1013", "CH02-1014", "CH02-1015", "CH02-1016", "CH02-1017", 
"CH02-1017", "CH02-1018", "CH02-1019", "CH02-1019", "CH02-1019", 
"CH02-102", "CH02-102", "CH02-1020", "CH02-1021", "CH02-1022", 
"CH02-1022"), date = structure(c(18789, 19014, 19041, 19048, 
18950, 18961, 18786, 18767, 18950, 18951, 18952, 18970, 18995, 
18996, 18860, 19043, 19045, 18702, 18709, 18814, 18818, 18846, 
18795, 18926, 18789, 18793, 18810, 18820, 18697, 18702, 18748, 
18765, 18783, 18785, 18796, 18901, 18690, 18966, 18817, 18825, 
18950, 18695, 18701, 18708, 18987, 19017, 18782, 18992, 18724, 
18739), class = "Date"), row = 1:50), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
df <- df %>% arrange(id_code, date)
sp_df <- split(df, df$id_code)

my_f <- function(x, cutoff=30){
  j <- 1
  while(j < nrow(x)){
    x <- x %>% filter((date - date[j]) <= 0 | (date - date[j]) > cutoff)
    j <- j+1
  }
  x
}

out <- bind_rows(
  lapply(sp_df, my_f))

out
#> # A tibble: 32 × 3
#>    id_code   date         row
#>    <chr>     <date>     <int>
#>  1 CH02-1    2021-06-11     1
#>  2 CH02-10   2022-01-22     2
#>  3 CH02-10   2022-02-25     4
#>  4 CH02-100  2021-11-19     5
#>  5 CH02-1000 2021-06-08     7
#>  6 CH02-1001 2021-05-20     8
#>  7 CH02-1002 2021-11-19     9
#>  8 CH02-1002 2022-01-03    13
#>  9 CH02-1003 2021-08-21    15
#> 10 CH02-1004 2022-02-20    16
#> # ℹ 22 more rows

Created on 2024-04-03 with reprex v2.0.2

Awesome, this seems to have done the trick.

So, this appears to work for the first two groups (a & b) but I have noticed, when applied to a larger dataset, for groups c and beyond that it starts to malfunction by no longer selecting the correct item to remove. Any thoughts? I am trying to troubleshoot as well.

Could you edit the question to include some of the data where it doesn't work?

Updated with more relevant data. Thank you for your assistance and patience!

@LeviM The updated answer should work now.  Let me know if otherwise.

Worked great! I was close trying to alter your function on my own. Much appreciated!

something like this?
df |>
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = '%m/%d/%y')) |>
  arrange(date) |>
  filter(date - lag(date, 1) > cutoff)

(note that your sample data are not in chronological order)

Opps I made that mistake when entering the dates, opps.

This will work under a lot of circumstances, but not all, I think.  Let's say date[2] is 20 days after date[1] and date[3] is 20 days after date[2].  In your code, both dates 2 and 3 would be dropped because they are both within the cutoff of the previous date.  I think given the OP's specification, date[3] should be retained because date[2] will get removed and date[3] will then be 40 days later than date[1] and thus will be retained.
